# React NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Dump of stacktrace from Kibana log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suS4C.png)

I'm very puzzled to what is causing this and I cannot reproduce it. I am not using any library that touches the **dom** other than React. I am using semantic-ui-react and importing the minified css from semantic-ui-css but that shouldn't be a problem I think (neither of these do any jquery shenanigans). The **ServiceOrderWrapper.js** is a Higher Order Component, that does a bunch of api calls and then updates state accordingly. Would be really helpful if anyone else has seen this error and solved it before, is there a good way to isolate the error?

```html
 this.reportPromise = ServiceOrderAPI.MakeReport(dto, this.state.name);
      this.reportPromise.promise
        .then(() => {
          this.handleGeneralApiSuccess(
            Wrapper.stateKeys.subContractorAction,
            { action: null, isSubmitting: false },
            'Serviceordern rapporterades som ingen åtgärd',
            this.state
          );
        })
        .catch(err => {
          if (!this.reportPromise.isCancel(err)) {
            this.handleGeneralApiError(
              Wrapper.stateKeys.subContractorAction,
              err.message
            );
          }
        });
        
        handleGeneralApiSuccess = (key, value, msg, prevState, extras = null) => {
          const callback = () => {
            if (msg != null && msg !== '') {
              this.props.appendFeedback({ isError: false, msg });
            }
            this.conditionalReload(key, prevState, extras);
          };
          this.setStateWrapper(key, value, callback);
        };
        
        setStateWrapper = (key, value, callback) => {
          this.setState(
            prevState => ({
              ...prevState,
              [key]: { ...prevState[key], ...value }
            }),
            callback
          );
        };
        
        conditionalReload = (action, state, extras = null) => {
  const reloadNecessary = shouldReloadServiceOrder(action, state, extras);
  if (!reloadNecessary) {
    return;
  } else {
    this.refresh();
  }
};

refresh = () => {
  this.setStateWrapper(
    Wrapper.stateKeys.load,
    { isReloading: true },
    this.loadFromServer
  );
};
```

**this.handleGeneralApiSuccess** is where the error happens, line 759 from the Kibana logg

In this scenario **shouldReloadServiceOrder** always returns true

Comment: It's not easy to understand what exactly is going on here. The `callback` function is part of the stack, so presumably something's going wrong there. Try to debug by eliminating lines until you have a [mcve]

And please use text instead of screendumps wherever possible. It makes it easier for people to help if the error log is plain text in the question body, instead of a image file.

Comment: Have you had any luck with your issue? I have a similar issue on IE (Chrome works ok) when I have a mixture of React and asp Panel partial updates (react Portal is replaced with each response).

Comment: It was a browser extension that edited the dom